# How to do smooth transition from one image to another

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

I have an activity where I am changing the *ImageView* periodically, for that I wrote the below line of code .

```
imageview.setImageUri(resId);
```

I am increasing the resource id .It  works fine but there is sudden transition from one image to another. I don't want that,I want the smooth transition of image view to another image. How can i do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
ImageView demoImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.DemoImage);
int imagesToShow[] = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,R.drawable.image3 };

animate(demoImage, imagesToShow, 0,false);  



  private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[], final int imageIndex, final boolean forever) {

  //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
  //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
  //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[] 
  //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

    int fadeInDuration = 500; // Configure time values here
    int timeBetween = 3000;
    int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);    //Visible or invisible by default - this will apply when the animation ends
    imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
    fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
    fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    imageView.setAnimation(animation);

    animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
                animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1,forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
            }
            else {
                if (forever == true){
                animate(imageView, images, 0,forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
                }
            }
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanx for fast reply. i voted u up .i am working on android 2.3, where as animation was added in android 3

Comment: Don't know if I come too late, but I was looking for an answer like this and it was awesome. Anyway, I figured out another way start the effect again. You can do `animate(imageView, images, imageIndex % images.length + 1,forever);` so the indexes will be always inside of bounds.

Comment: Why is it that when i translate this to kotlin code, the AlphaAnimation wont work. When it is translated, it tells me that I have to create a function for it even though it is clearly part of the library?

Answer (score 2):

Try alpha animation. First fadeout the imageview, on animation end, change the resource and then fadein the imageview.

Comment: i am working on android 2.3, where as animation was added in android 3

Comment: alpha animation is available from API level 1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html

Answer (score 1):

For a smooth transition you must use Animations in Android, start by reading the following link:
http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidAnimation/article.html

There are many similar questions on stackoverflow about animations and many tutorials are available on the net about this topic. A simple search on google will bring you tons of result

Comment: i am working on android 2.3, where as animation was added in android 3