# What are different image transitions available in android

Tags: java, android, image, android-studio

I want to set transition effect to images.

I tried fade-in fade-out method (the one suggested in this link [How to do smooth transition from one image to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587152/how-to-do-smooth-transition-from-one-image-to-another)).

I want to try few more effects in android studio and should be supported by Android 4.1 OS and onwards.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

I am giving some links you should check them out, upvote if you like

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-android-transitions--cms-21640
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/29/image-transition-animation-in-android/

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/6

Comment: Try Smartherd's tutorials about animation on YouTube.